# Animate a UINavigationController pushViewController like a presentViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uimodalpresentationstyle

I have a viewController in a UINavigationController that I need to push onto the navigation stack, but instead of the traditional push animation style, it needs to look like the default modal presentation style used in `presentViewController`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You are going to need to use a custom transition, here is a basic tutorial to get you started https://www.raywenderlich.com/322-custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions-getting-started

Comment: @JustinM was hoping to possibly get some code relative to the modal presentation to start me off. any suggestions?

Comment: I don't really have the time but this link has all the code samples https://medium.com/@samstone/create-custom-uinavigationcontroller-transitions-in-ios-1acd6a0b6d25. Then just animate the `toView` up on pushing and `fromView` down on popping.